# Unexpected character ('}' during JSON desearilization

Tags: apex, json, callout, apexrest, parser

I get a JSON response from external system in the `resposne.body()`

The JSON looks like this:

```
"[{\"workOrderNumber\":\"WO-02612\",\"workOrderId\":\"a3F5C000000LHB0UAO\",\"processingStatus\":\"Open\"}]"
```

I created a class in my org to deserialize the json.

```
public class ResponseJSON{

public String sampleNumber;
public String SampleID;
public String state;

}
```

I did get an error when deserializing the json saying it's a Malformed JSOn because `'{'` is missing, so it wasn't the correct JSON format. So added the `'{'` and `'}'` in the beginning and end of JSON when deserializing the JSON.

```
ResponseJSON respJson =(ResponseJSON)JSON.deserialize('{' + response.getBody() + '}', ResponseJSON.class);
```

But this gives me an error:

```
"common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Unexpected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value at {the above line}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your JSON is an array of response class, so please try next instead **JSON.deserialize(...,List<ResponseJSON>.class);**

Comment: @kurunve making it as a List I now get an error - "common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you add the curly brackets, your JSON looks like this

```
{
  [
    {
     \"sampleNumber\":\"WO-02609\",
     \"SampleID\":\"a3F5C000000CHATTAM\",
     \"state\":\"Open\"
   }
 ]
}
```

Which is invalid JSON because you have an list inside of an object without a property name. Instead of adding the curly brackets, change your code to deserialize the JSON differently:

```
List<ResponseJSON> respJson =(List<ResponseJSON>)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), List<ResponseJSON>.class);
```

Since your JSON starts with square brackets, it's read as a list. Ergo, you should deserialize it as one.

**Update**

Since you mention in the comments that the external system is adding quotes to your code, I suspect you can do this to make the string JSON-friendly before deserializing

```
String jsonString = (String)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(), String.class); 

List<ResponseJSON> respJson =(List<ResponseJSON>)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<ResponseJSON>.class);
```

Comment: This is a list, serialized into JSON... creating a string... which has then been serialized to JSON *again* (hence the backslashed double-quotes.)

Comment: I agree @SebastianKessel. +1, the safest thing, if this is what the external system does, would be  to deserialize it into a string, and then deserialize *that* result into a list.